# Show button in Tkinter when mouse is over window

Tags: python, tkinter, button, mouseover

I am having problems with showing a button when mouse is over a window. When I go over the window, the button shows up. But when I go over the button, it hides again. However, when I tried to recreate the problem with a simple program, it works fine... But something else bugs me in the short version.

```
import Tkinter as TK

root = TK.Tk()
root.geometry("400x300")
root.overrideredirect(True)

button = TK.Button(root, text = "HI", command = lambda: root.destroy())

def Show(event):
    button.place(x = 0, y = 0, width = 60, height = 30)

def Hide(event):
    button.place_forget()

root.bind("<Enter>", Show)
root.bind("<Leave>", Hide)

root.mainloop()
```

This short version works. But when you go over the button and then away from it, it hides. Even though you are still above the root window. Is there any easy way of forcing the button to be visible all the time the mouse si over the root? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check whether your mouse event was outside or inside the root frame and act accordingly

```
def Hide(event):
    x, y = event.x, event.y
    x_r, y_r = root.winfo_x(), root.winfo_y()
    if x > x_r + root.winfo_width() or x < x_r or y > y_r + root.winfo_height() or y < y_r:
        button.place_forget()
```

Comment: `event.x` and `event.`y are in the window itself... so I had to change it to `if x > root.winfo_width() or x < 0 or y > root.winfo_height() or y < 0:`

Comment: x_r and y_r should be 0 when root.overrideredirect(True) so I don't understand your point. Didn't it work just as I posted it? I used python 3.6 so maybe there is a difference here.

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot to mention that in the original program I made a few functions to move the window around. And after moving it from the original position the Hide funtion did not work anymore. I use python 2.7

Answer (score 3):

You `Enter` and `Leave` events fires twice (over root window and over button), because when you `Enter` button widget - you `Leave` root, so to solve problem you can check `widget.master` and act if there's no master.

```
try:
    import tkinter as TK
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as TK

root = TK.Tk()
root.geometry("400x300")
root.overrideredirect(True)
button = TK.Button(root, text="HI", command=root.destroy)


def Show(event):
    print('Show event triggered by %s' % event.widget.__class__)
    print('Master container is %s' % event.widget.master)

    if event.widget.master is None:
        button.place(x=0, y=0, width=60, height=30)


def Hide(event):
    print('Hide event triggered by %s' % event.widget.__class__)
    print('Master container is %s' % event.widget.master)

    if event.widget.master is None:
        button.place_forget()


root.bind("<Enter>", Show)
root.bind("<Leave>", Hide)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: this solution is nice.